# В чем разница между этми записями?

Tags: java, классы

У меня есть класс Car, и я хочу создать его экземпляр. Можно написать:

```
Car car;

Car car = new Car();
```

В чем заключается разница между этми двумя записями?

Comment: Результат чего один и тот же? Где результат?

Comment: Извините, немного подкорректирую свой вопрос. Просто в чем разница между этими двумя записями?

Comment: Кхм, кхм, первая только декларирует переменную, а вторая - декларирует, создает объект и присваивает переменной ссылку на него.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом случаи вы просто объявляете ссылку на объект и не больше. У вашего Car, скорее всего есть поля, например, *width*, *speed*, и так далее. Данная запись их не затрагивает, их значение - не определено. С такой машинкой нельзя пока что ничего делать, кроме как инициализировать её.
Во втором случаи вы вызываете метод, в данном случае - это конструктор. Теперь с этой машиной можно полноправно работать. Конструктор будет пустым, его поля = **null**.
Если вы хотите увидеть кардинальное отличие, давайте представим такую ситуацию - у вас есть приложение в котором очень сильно ограничена память. Когда вы написали первую строчку, а затем запустили программу, много место не ушло. Во втором случаи, к примеру, о нашей машинке в конструкторе дается очень много информации, запускаются другие файлы, подкачиваются библиотеки...
В таком случаи в воображаемом приложении не хватит памяти, и оно вылетит.

Answer (score 1):

Первый случай `Car car;` со вторым объединяет только то, что есть переменная типа `Car`. Для локальной переменной вам придется присвоить ей значение, иначе код просто не скомпилируется. Для переменной экземпляра, у нее будет ссылка по умолчанию на объект `null` `Car car = null;`

Во втором же случае

```
Car car = new Car();
```

командой `new` мы создаем новый экземпляр (объект) класса `Car` и присваиваем переменной ссылку на него. Т.о.

- у нас есть переменная

- есть новый объект (в куче выделена память и заполнена данными объекта)

- у переменной есть ссылка на объект, и можно не опасаться `NullPointerException`

- у объекта есть как минимум одна действующая ссылка на него, а значит он доступен для работы, и в обозримом будущем сборщик мусора ему не страшен
Получается, что в недрах JVM создана целая, хоть и небольшая, но функциональная и рабочая структура.